# Executing custom function on MongoDB using Casbah/Scala

Tags: scala, mongodb, casbah

I've defined a function in MongoDB using its command line client.

```
function something(){...}
```

I was wondering how can I execute a custom MongoDB function using casbah from Scala.

Any recommendations ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to run arbitrary javascript code on the server. You can supply it as a string from
the client and send it to the server for evaluation, or install the function on the server
first, as documented here:
  http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/server-side-javascript/

Server-side functions are registered per db, in a collection called system.js.

Either way, you can then use the the db.eval() command to call your code, as shown here:

```
/* Call like so:
     evalJavascript(myDB, "function (oid) { return coll.find({_id: oid}); }", someObjectId)
*/
def evalJavascript(db:MongoDB, func: String, args: String*): Validation[String, Object] = {
  val result = db.command(Map(
    "eval" -> func,
    "args" -> args.toList
  ));

  if (result.ok) {
    result.get("retval").success
  } else {
    result.getErrorMessage().failure
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about MapReduce jobs, written in JavaScript? If so, you can use `.mapReduce(...)` method of collection, but you need to specify map, reduce and finalize functions.
[Here is the example](https://github.com/mongodb/casbah/blob/master/casbah-core/src/test/scala/MapReduceSpec.scala#L103).

If you're talking about executing arbitrary JavaScript code, I think it is not possible (why don't you use scala for object manipulations?).