# MongoDB and Scala

Tags: mongodb, scala

I am trying to execute the code proposed by [in this answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33915687/1460445) from Scala.

[In this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10159475/executing-custom-function-on-mongodb-using-casbah-scala), it is shown how to do this using Casbah; but as far as I have understood, Casbah is deprecated, and the mongo-scala-driver should be used.

How do I execute a custom code as the one [proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33915687/1460445) from scala?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use [Reactive Mongo](http://reactivemongo.org/), this Drive is Asynchronous & Non-Blocking by default. And for a best performance try to execute your query on the Mongo side not on Scala side.

Comment: Thank you! I found how to add the script on the Mongo side, but still how can I call it from scala?

Comment: It's a query right? You should be able to run as a mongo query through the mongo driver. It would be useful see what do you have.